# How to click on a map area only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a medical assessment and there is this page where you can select the body parts which are in pain. Once you click on a body part, the name of it will be displayed below. The problem is it will display multiple times when clicked repeatedly. Is there a way to block the click event from repeating?

Here is the sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/qpmxnv2g/6/

```
var map = document.getElementById("Map");
map.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    callAction(e.target);
});
map.one("click", function (e) {
    callAction(e.target);
});

var body = [];
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = body;

function callAction(area) {
    body.push(area.title);
    document.getElementById("body").value = body;
}

document.getElementById("Clear").addEventListener('click', function () {
    body.length = 0;
    document.getElementById("body").value = '';
});
```

Comment: You can create a flag for the `area` which tells you've already clicked it, or remove the listener or remove the `area`. jQuery has also [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) ...

Answer (score 1):

change your function like this:-

```
function callAction(area) {
    if (body.indexOf(area.title) !== -1) { return; }
    body.push(area.title);
    document.getElementById("body").value = body;     
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qpmxnv2g/9/)

Comment: I would suggest that method too. Except that for clarity, I think `if (body.indexOf(area.title) !== -1) { return; }` might be better.